# How to make multiple <g> objects clickable within one SVG

Tags: object, svg, hyperlink

So I have read at least 10 other similar questions but none of the solutions seem to work for me.

**What I am trying to do:**

I have a bunch of SVG code that makes a tiny city. I want to make each building link to a different webpage.

- Sorry for the messy code.

---

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

</head>
<body>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="800px"
         height="800px" viewBox="0 0 800 800" enable-background="new 0 0 800 800" xml:space="preserve">

        <defs>
            <filter id="f1" x="0" y="0">
                <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="4" />
            </filter>
        </defs>

            <g>
                <path fill="#ABABAA" d="M502.987,318.81l-9.145,1.983c-0.385-0.433-0.822-0.721-1.267-0.792c0.379-0.752,0.498-1.841,0.247-2.995
                    c-0.289-1.332-0.986-2.379-1.771-2.831c-0.005-0.458-0.047-0.935-0.153-1.424c-0.516-2.377-2.087-4.052-3.514-3.743
                    c-0.012,0.004-0.023,0.013-0.033,0.014c-0.855-3.094-2.835-5.229-4.617-4.843c-1.389,0.3-2.256,2.055-2.333,4.318
                    c-0.495-0.408-1.028-0.6-1.539-0.488c-0.959,0.206-1.557,1.412-1.619,2.966c-0.567-0.415-1.169-0.608-1.745-0.484
                    c-1.413,0.306-2.2,2.346-1.98,4.802c-0.369-0.147-0.744-0.207-1.109-0.129c-1.637,0.355-2.442,3.036-1.802,5.993
                    c0.048,0.218,0.113,0.415,0.174,0.622c-0.722,0.723-1.013,2.283-0.644,3.984c0.346,1.595,1.17,2.843,2.057,3.291
                    c-0.162,0.92-0.143,1.982,0.094,3.082c0.632,2.905,2.554,4.952,4.296,4.574c0.2-0.044,0.39-0.126,0.569-0.227
                    c0.494,0.929,1.2,1.548,1.91,1.619c0.63,1.739,1.775,2.963,2.939,3.135c0.673,2.367,2.28,3.978,3.762,3.658
                    c0.855-0.185,1.476-0.987,1.786-2.09c0.596,1.074,1.474,1.716,2.297,1.538c0.874-0.191,1.43-1.244,1.473-2.577
                    c0.534,0.355,1.105,0.517,1.656,0.396c1.521-0.329,2.322-2.571,1.88-5.082c0.008-0.002,0.014,0,0.021-0.002
                    c1.848-0.399,2.804-3.22,2.135-6.302c-0.428-1.974-1.417-3.563-2.56-4.353c0.064-0.083,0.107-0.197,0.163-0.294l8.416-1.825
                    h-0.042V318.81z"/>
                <path fill="#634E42" d="M502.987,284.44v34.37v5.496h0.042h10.386v-38.75c-1.239,1.169-2.891,1.902-4.729,1.902
                    C506.311,287.458,504.236,286.258,502.987,284.44z"/>
                <path fill="#81AE84" d="M549.442,261.866c0-4.596-2.966-8.53-7.217-10.327c0.973-1.284,1.555-2.834,1.555-4.522
                    c0-3.17-2.034-5.884-4.951-7.144c1.017-1.506,1.634-3.273,1.634-5.179c0-4.67-3.54-8.561-8.279-9.543
                    c0.43-1.065,0.696-2.206,0.696-3.41c0-5.411-4.744-9.795-10.608-9.795c-0.431,0-0.835,0.069-1.25,0.118
                    c-1.071-2.77-3.909-4.759-7.281-4.759c-3.164,0-5.864,1.747-7.079,4.245c-1.674-1.145-3.693-1.816-5.874-1.816
                    c-5.762,0-10.428,4.665-10.428,10.427c0,0.666,0.079,1.318,0.198,1.949c-1.965,0.929-3.426,2.735-3.855,4.927
                    c-3.549,0.8-6.339,3.58-7.143,7.13c-4.759,0.508-8.472,4.482-8.472,9.373c0,2.83,1.264,5.338,3.224,7.075
                    c-2.275,1.14-3.855,3.471-3.855,6.195c0,2.894,1.768,5.366,4.275,6.414c-0.893,1.445-1.433,3.134-1.433,4.961
                    c0,5.025,3.916,9.088,8.853,9.413c0,0.025-0.006,0.045-0.006,0.065c0,6.11,4.947,11.058,11.06,11.058
                    c3.914,0,7.33-2.039,9.296-5.105c0.145,0.286,0.308,0.561,0.487,0.822c1.249,1.818,3.324,3.018,5.698,3.018
                    c1.839,0,3.49-0.733,4.729-1.902c0.976-0.92,1.701-2.104,2.019-3.454c1.268,1.709,3.283,2.829,5.572,2.829
                    c2.643,0,4.908-1.487,6.088-3.654c0.869,0.297,1.788,0.494,2.76,0.494c4.715,0,8.531-3.815,8.531-8.531
                    c0-0.039-0.011-0.078-0.011-0.117C544.585,272.539,549.442,267.755,549.442,261.866z"/>
            </g>
            <g class="contact">
                <polygon fill="#E19190" points="323.274,315.865 323.274,383.485 378.57,410.467 378.57,342.846       "/>
                <polygon fill="#576D88" points="344.127,339.484 344.127,348.713 351.673,352.396 351.673,343.166         "/>
                <polygon fill="#E7A7A6" points="378.57,342.849 378.57,410.469 471.507,365.832 471.507,298.877       "/>
                <polygon fill="#E1E1E5" points="479.992,307.993 478.396,308.748 478.396,323.463 479.992,322.697         "/>
                <polygon fill="#E1E1E5" points="419.792,342.757 419.792,376.337 465.945,354.17 465.945,320.92       "/>
                <polygon fill="#798AA0" points="421.202,343.941 421.202,374.003 464.421,353.149 464.421,323.384         "/>
                <polygon fill="#E1E1E5" points="413.26,346.012 395.126,354.591 395.126,402.516 413.26,393.807       "/>
                <polygon fill="#798AA0" points="412.034,348.044 396.352,355.465 396.352,389.695 412.034,382.163         "/>
                <polygon fill="#D9D9DF" points="323.276,315.866 378.576,342.849 471.511,298.875 417.217,273.874         "/>
                <polygon fill="#576D88" points="382.776,303.51 402.701,313.232 436.186,297.388 416.624,288.379      "/>
                <polygon fill="#E1E1E5" points="468.005,302.13 466.36,302.876 478.394,308.754 479.994,307.996       "/>
                <polygon fill="#576D88" points="417.456,281.649 459.75,301.07 464.018,299.051 417.101,277.5 331.67,315.642 336.277,317.89       
                    "/>
                <polygon fill="#D9D9DF" points="466.365,302.877 466.365,317.592 478.397,323.463 478.397,308.749         "/>
                <polygon fill="#ABABAA" points="466.36,302.879 466.36,317.591 464.27,317.084 464.27,302.477         "/>
                <polygon fill="#ABABAA" points="378.571,410.471 323.272,383.482 310.109,383.482 361.236,410.5       "/>
            </g>
            <g class="work">
                <polygon fill="#D5C8B2" points="330.181,352.667 330.181,436.629 141.844,528.766 141.844,422.516 177.281,422.531 
                    177.281,404.978 212.69,404.978 212.69,387.539 247.293,387.539 247.293,370.104 283.238,370.641 283.238,353.741       "/>
                <polygon fill="#CABA9F" points="141.833,422.523 53.313,378.932 53.313,479.658 141.833,528.758       "/>
                <polygon fill="#575756" points="212.713,405.078 124.804,361.571 88.759,361.471 177.29,405.071       "/>
                <polygon fill="#797978" points="212.698,387.636 212.692,405.065 124.772,361.573 124.809,343.564         "/>
                <polygon fill="#575756" points="177.276,422.531 88.834,379.024 53.322,378.924 141.853,422.524       "/>
                <polygon fill="#797978" points="177.297,405.063 177.255,422.519 88.813,379.026 88.781,361.469       "/>
                <polygon fill="#575756" points="247.3,387.629 159.236,343.289 124.816,343.57 212.692,387.629        "/>
                <polygon fill="#797978" points="247.294,370.189 247.294,387.623 159.257,343.301 159.242,326.122         "/>
                <polygon fill="#575756" points="283.242,370.735 195.253,327.204 159.238,326.125 247.3,370.208       "/>
                <polygon fill="#575756" points="330.183,352.753 237.099,309.099 195.257,310.04 283.22,353.831       "/>
                <polygon fill="#797978" points="283.242,353.831 283.236,370.735 195.246,327.207 195.253,310.038         "/>
                <polygon fill="#D5C8B2" points="255.452,334.799 272.72,334.448 267.819,265.029 255.452,265.029      "/>
                <polygon fill="#CABA9F" points="243.668,329.11 255.46,334.755 255.46,265.031 248.043,263.045        "/>
                <polygon fill="#575756" points="267.825,265.031 255.46,265.036 248.049,263.045 259.594,263.045      "/>
                <g>
                    <polygon fill="#575756" points="224.034,488.68 170.469,514.657 170.469,455.978 224.134,430.006          "/>
                    <polygon fill="#797978" points="224.034,488.68 170.469,514.657 170.469,510.574 224.034,484.595          "/>
                    <polygon fill="#797978" points="224.034,480.861 170.469,506.842 170.469,502.757 224.034,476.779             "/>
                    <polygon fill="#797978" points="224.034,473.044 170.469,499.023 170.469,494.941 224.034,468.961             "/>
                    <polygon fill="#797978" points="224.034,465.228 170.469,491.206 170.469,487.124 224.034,461.145             "/>
                    <polygon fill="#797978" points="224.034,457.41 170.469,483.391 170.469,479.306 224.034,453.327          "/>
                    <polygon fill="#797978" points="224.034,449.594 170.469,475.573 170.469,471.49 224.034,445.51           "/>
                    <polygon fill="#797978" points="224.034,441.776 170.469,467.756 170.469,463.674 224.034,437.694             "/>
                    <polygon fill="#797978" points="224.034,433.961 170.469,459.939 170.469,455.856 224.034,429.876             "/>
                </g>
                <g>
                    <polygon fill="#575756" points="313.025,445.026 263.011,469.282 263.011,414.492 313.119,390.241             "/>
                    <polygon fill="#797978" points="313.025,445.026 263.011,469.282 263.011,465.47 313.025,441.212          "/>
                    <polygon fill="#797978" points="313.025,437.727 263.011,461.984 263.011,458.171 313.025,433.915             "/>
                    <polygon fill="#797978" points="313.025,430.427 263.011,454.685 263.011,450.873 313.025,426.614             "/>
                    <polygon fill="#797978" points="313.025,423.13 263.011,447.386 263.011,443.574 313.025,419.316          "/>
                    <polygon fill="#797978" points="313.025,415.829 263.011,440.088 263.011,436.273 313.025,412.017             "/>
                    <polygon fill="#797978" points="313.025,408.531 263.011,432.789 263.011,428.977 313.025,404.718             "/>
                    <polygon fill="#797978" points="313.025,401.231 263.011,425.489 263.011,421.678 313.025,397.42          "/>
                    <polygon fill="#797978" points="313.025,393.935 263.011,418.19 263.011,414.379 313.025,390.12           "/>
                </g>
                <polygon fill="#ABABAA" points="141.797,528.752 53.281,479.652 29,479.652 110.32,528.832        "/>
            </g>
            <g class="about">
                <polygon fill="#798AA0" points="750.926,326.083 750.926,404.376 691.513,432.475 691.513,353.721         "/>
                <polygon fill="#E1E1E5" points="735.656,354.756 713.323,365.145 713.323,422.307 735.656,411.745         "/>
                <polygon fill="#576D88" points="691.513,353.72 691.513,432.474 597.56,387.8 597.56,311.595      "/>
                <polygon fill="#D9D9DF" points="617.513,347.591 617.513,360.963 601.56,353.378 601.56,340.439       "/>
                <polygon fill="#D9D9DF" points="639.513,357.258 639.513,370.629 623.56,363.044 623.56,350.105       "/>
                <polygon fill="#D9D9DF" points="661.513,366.924 661.513,380.296 645.56,372.711 645.56,359.772       "/>
                <polygon fill="#D9D9DF" points="683.513,376.591 683.513,389.962 667.56,382.377 667.56,369.439       "/>
                <polygon fill="#E7A7A6" points="750.925,326.084 718.686,287.855 695.659,296.606 691.515,353.715         "/>
                <polygon fill="#E19190" points="695.663,296.61 691.51,353.721 597.56,311.589 597.56,249.174         "/>
                <polygon fill="#EDBDBC" points="718.688,287.856 597.563,233.053 597.563,249.173 695.657,296.61      "/>
                <polygon fill="#798AA0" points="597.56,173.183 597.56,387.8 564.861,402.538 564.861,186.54      "/>
                <polygon fill="#576D88" points="564.861,186.54 564.86,402.538 519.46,382.403 519.46,164.561         "/>
                <polygon fill="#D9D9DF" points="536.195,202.642 536.195,241.032 528.126,237.453 528.126,198.735         "/>
                <polygon fill="#D9D9DF" points="551.861,208.309 551.861,246.699 543.792,243.12 543.792,204.402      "/>
                <polygon fill="#D9D9DF" points="536.195,256.309 536.195,294.699 528.126,291.12 528.126,252.402      "/>
                <polygon fill="#D9D9DF" points="551.861,261.976 551.861,300.366 543.792,296.787 543.792,258.069         "/>
                <polygon fill="#D9D9DF" points="536.195,309.976 536.195,348.366 528.126,344.787 528.126,306.069         "/>
                <polygon fill="#D9D9DF" points="551.861,315.643 551.861,354.033 543.792,350.454 543.792,311.736         "/>
                <polygon fill="#E7A7A6" points="597.559,173.184 564.859,186.541 555.649,102.719         "/>
                <polygon fill="#E19190" points="519.46,164.562 564.859,186.54 555.65,102.722        "/>
                <polygon fill="#ABABAA" points="519.407,382.439 498.485,382.45 540.376,402.548 564.876,402.548      "/>
                <polygon fill="#ABABAA" points="691.513,432.474 669.834,432.474 586.157,392.939 597.563,387.798         "/>
            </g>
            <g>
                <path fill="#ABABAA" d="M689.987,525.81l-9.145,1.983c-0.385-0.433-0.822-0.721-1.267-0.792c0.379-0.752,0.498-1.841,0.247-2.995
                    c-0.289-1.332-0.986-2.379-1.771-2.831c-0.005-0.458-0.047-0.935-0.153-1.424c-0.516-2.377-2.087-4.052-3.514-3.743
                    c-0.012,0.004-0.023,0.013-0.033,0.014c-0.855-3.094-2.835-5.228-4.617-4.843c-1.389,0.3-2.256,2.055-2.333,4.318
                    c-0.495-0.408-1.028-0.6-1.539-0.488c-0.959,0.206-1.557,1.412-1.619,2.966c-0.567-0.415-1.169-0.608-1.745-0.484
                    c-1.413,0.306-2.2,2.346-1.98,4.802c-0.369-0.148-0.744-0.207-1.109-0.129c-1.637,0.354-2.442,3.036-1.802,5.993
                    c0.048,0.218,0.113,0.415,0.174,0.622c-0.722,0.723-1.013,2.283-0.644,3.984c0.346,1.595,1.17,2.843,2.057,3.291
                    c-0.162,0.92-0.143,1.982,0.094,3.082c0.632,2.905,2.554,4.952,4.296,4.574c0.2-0.044,0.39-0.126,0.569-0.227
                    c0.494,0.929,1.2,1.548,1.91,1.619c0.63,1.739,1.775,2.963,2.939,3.135c0.673,2.367,2.28,3.979,3.762,3.658
                    c0.855-0.185,1.477-0.987,1.786-2.09c0.596,1.074,1.474,1.716,2.297,1.538c0.874-0.192,1.43-1.244,1.473-2.577
                    c0.534,0.355,1.104,0.517,1.656,0.396c1.521-0.329,2.322-2.571,1.88-5.082c0.008-0.002,0.014,0,0.021-0.002
                    c1.848-0.399,2.804-3.22,2.135-6.302c-0.428-1.974-1.417-3.563-2.56-4.352c0.064-0.083,0.107-0.197,0.163-0.294l8.416-1.825
                    h-0.042V525.81z"/>
                <path fill="#634E42" d="M689.987,491.44v34.37v5.496h0.042h10.386v-38.75c-1.239,1.169-2.891,1.902-4.729,1.902
                    C693.311,494.458,691.236,493.258,689.987,491.44z"/>
                <path fill="#81AE84" d="M736.442,468.866c0-4.596-2.966-8.53-7.217-10.327c0.973-1.284,1.555-2.834,1.555-4.522
                    c0-3.17-2.034-5.884-4.951-7.144c1.017-1.506,1.634-3.273,1.634-5.179c0-4.67-3.54-8.561-8.279-9.543
                    c0.43-1.065,0.696-2.206,0.696-3.41c0-5.411-4.744-9.795-10.608-9.795c-0.431,0-0.835,0.069-1.25,0.118
                    c-1.071-2.77-3.909-4.759-7.281-4.759c-3.164,0-5.864,1.747-7.079,4.245c-1.674-1.145-3.693-1.816-5.874-1.816
                    c-5.762,0-10.428,4.665-10.428,10.427c0,0.666,0.079,1.318,0.198,1.949c-1.965,0.929-3.426,2.735-3.855,4.927
                    c-3.549,0.8-6.339,3.58-7.143,7.13c-4.759,0.508-8.472,4.482-8.472,9.373c0,2.83,1.264,5.338,3.224,7.075
                    c-2.275,1.14-3.855,3.471-3.855,6.195c0,2.894,1.768,5.366,4.275,6.414c-0.893,1.445-1.433,3.134-1.433,4.961
                    c0,5.025,3.916,9.088,8.852,9.413c0,0.025-0.006,0.045-0.006,0.065c0,6.11,4.947,11.058,11.06,11.058
                    c3.914,0,7.33-2.039,9.296-5.105c0.144,0.286,0.308,0.561,0.487,0.822c1.249,1.818,3.324,3.018,5.698,3.018
                    c1.839,0,3.49-0.733,4.729-1.902c0.976-0.92,1.701-2.104,2.019-3.454c1.268,1.709,3.283,2.829,5.572,2.829
                    c2.643,0,4.908-1.487,6.088-3.654c0.869,0.297,1.788,0.494,2.76,0.494c4.715,0,8.531-3.815,8.531-8.531
                    c0-0.039-0.011-0.078-0.011-0.117C731.585,479.539,736.442,474.755,736.442,468.866z"/>
            </g>
            <g>
                <path fill="#ABABAA" d="M110.487,562.31l-9.145,1.983c-0.385-0.433-0.822-0.721-1.267-0.792c0.379-0.752,0.498-1.841,0.247-2.995
                    c-0.289-1.332-0.986-2.379-1.771-2.831c-0.005-0.458-0.047-0.935-0.153-1.424c-0.516-2.377-2.087-4.052-3.514-3.743
                    c-0.012,0.004-0.023,0.013-0.033,0.014c-0.855-3.094-2.835-5.228-4.617-4.843c-1.389,0.3-2.256,2.055-2.333,4.318
                    c-0.495-0.408-1.028-0.6-1.539-0.488c-0.959,0.206-1.557,1.412-1.619,2.966c-0.567-0.415-1.169-0.608-1.745-0.484
                    c-1.413,0.306-2.2,2.346-1.98,4.802c-0.369-0.148-0.744-0.207-1.109-0.129c-1.637,0.354-2.442,3.036-1.802,5.993
                    c0.048,0.218,0.113,0.415,0.174,0.622c-0.722,0.723-1.013,2.283-0.644,3.984c0.346,1.595,1.17,2.843,2.057,3.291
                    c-0.162,0.92-0.144,1.982,0.094,3.082c0.632,2.905,2.554,4.952,4.296,4.574c0.2-0.044,0.39-0.126,0.569-0.227
                    c0.494,0.929,1.2,1.548,1.91,1.619c0.63,1.739,1.775,2.963,2.938,3.135c0.673,2.367,2.28,3.979,3.762,3.658
                    c0.855-0.185,1.476-0.987,1.786-2.09c0.596,1.074,1.474,1.716,2.297,1.538c0.874-0.192,1.43-1.244,1.473-2.577
                    c0.534,0.355,1.104,0.517,1.656,0.396c1.52-0.329,2.322-2.571,1.88-5.082c0.008-0.002,0.014,0,0.021-0.002
                    c1.848-0.399,2.804-3.22,2.135-6.302c-0.428-1.974-1.417-3.563-2.561-4.352c0.064-0.083,0.107-0.197,0.163-0.294l8.416-1.825
                    h-0.042V562.31z"/>
                <path fill="#634E42" d="M110.487,527.94v34.37v5.496h0.042h10.386v-38.75c-1.239,1.169-2.891,1.902-4.73,1.902
                    C113.812,530.958,111.736,529.758,110.487,527.94z"/>
                <path fill="#81AE84" d="M156.942,505.366c0-4.596-2.966-8.53-7.217-10.327c0.973-1.284,1.555-2.834,1.555-4.522
                    c0-3.17-2.034-5.884-4.951-7.144c1.017-1.506,1.634-3.273,1.634-5.179c0-4.67-3.54-8.561-8.279-9.543
                    c0.43-1.065,0.696-2.206,0.696-3.41c0-5.411-4.744-9.795-10.608-9.795c-0.431,0-0.835,0.069-1.25,0.118
                    c-1.071-2.77-3.909-4.759-7.281-4.759c-3.164,0-5.864,1.747-7.079,4.245c-1.674-1.145-3.693-1.816-5.874-1.816
                    c-5.762,0-10.428,4.665-10.428,10.427c0,0.666,0.079,1.318,0.198,1.949c-1.965,0.929-3.426,2.735-3.855,4.927
                    c-3.549,0.8-6.339,3.58-7.144,7.13c-4.759,0.508-8.472,4.482-8.472,9.373c0,2.83,1.264,5.338,3.224,7.075
                    c-2.275,1.14-3.855,3.471-3.855,6.195c0,2.894,1.768,5.366,4.275,6.414c-0.893,1.445-1.433,3.134-1.433,4.961
                    c0,5.025,3.916,9.088,8.853,9.413c0,0.025-0.006,0.045-0.006,0.066c0,6.11,4.947,11.058,11.06,11.058
                    c3.914,0,7.33-2.039,9.296-5.104c0.145,0.286,0.308,0.56,0.487,0.822c1.249,1.818,3.324,3.018,5.698,3.018
                    c1.839,0,3.49-0.733,4.73-1.902c0.976-0.92,1.701-2.104,2.019-3.454c1.269,1.709,3.283,2.829,5.572,2.829
                    c2.643,0,4.908-1.487,6.088-3.654c0.869,0.297,1.788,0.494,2.76,0.494c4.715,0,8.531-3.815,8.531-8.531
                    c0-0.039-0.011-0.078-0.011-0.117C152.085,516.039,156.942,511.255,156.942,505.366z"/>
            </g>
            <g>
                <g>
                    <polygon fill="none" points="386.887,481.157 386.964,497.627 386.889,481.157 386.888,481.157            "/>
                    <polygon fill="none" points="394.864,495.059 405.099,489.348 405.095,489.347            "/>
                    <polygon fill="none" points="363.381,512.62 363.384,512.618 363.381,512.617             "/>
                    <polygon fill="none" points="367.97,472.557 353.97,466.211 367.957,472.56           "/>
                    <polygon fill="none" points="388.688,498.503 388.674,495.596 388.688,498.503            "/>
                    <polygon fill="#E19190" points="390.309,481.019 390.309,481.022 421.182,464.771             "/>
                    <polygon fill="#E19190" points="405.095,489.347 405.099,489.348 438.26,470.849 423.418,465.566 423.418,479.119          "/>
                    <polygon fill="#E19190" points="386.888,481.156 386.888,481.157 386.889,481.157 386.889,481.133 367.97,472.557 
                        367.957,472.56          "/>
                    <polygon fill="#E19190" points="388.61,481.914 388.611,481.912 388.61,481.912           "/>
                    <polygon fill="#E19190" points="363.46,529.102 363.46,529.1 363.457,529.101             "/>
                    <path fill="#E19190" d="M363.381,512.62v-0.003l-38.598-21.238h0l-0.002-0.002v14.49l38.675,23.233l-0.078-16.48H363.381z
                         M327.921,504.18c-1.084,0-1.962-1.955-1.962-4.366c0-2.412,0.878-4.367,1.962-4.367c1.083,0,1.961,1.955,1.961,4.367
                        C329.882,502.225,329.004,504.18,327.921,504.18z M358.297,521.521c-1.293,0-2.341-2.182-2.341-4.874
                        c0-2.691,1.048-4.872,2.341-4.872c1.293,0,2.342,2.181,2.342,4.872C360.639,519.339,359.591,521.521,358.297,521.521z"/>
                    <polygon fill="#D9D9DF" points="386.964,497.627 386.887,481.157 386.888,481.157 386.888,481.156 367.957,472.56 
                        353.97,466.211 352.626,465.602 352.626,480.09 353.706,480.641           "/>
                    <path fill="#E7A7A6" d="M438.261,470.849L438.261,470.849l-33.162,18.499l-10.235,5.711l-4.447,2.48l-0.108-16.518v-0.003
                        l-1.698,0.894l-0.001,0.002l-0.004,0.001l0.068,13.681l0.014,2.907h0l-0.004,0.001l0.002,0.002l-25.301,14.112h-0.001
                        l-0.003,0.002h-0.001l0.078,16.48l0.003-0.001l17.785-10.724c-0.321-1.899-0.272-4.04,0.236-6.164
                        c1.276-5.332,4.923-8.522,8.145-7.122c1.927,0.835,3.258,3.125,3.75,5.97l22.615-13.636c-0.388-1.981-0.362-4.249,0.177-6.501
                        c1.276-5.333,4.923-8.522,8.145-7.124c2.004,0.869,3.37,3.309,3.811,6.311l10.137-6.113V470.849z"/>
                    <ellipse fill="#D9D9DF" cx="358.297" cy="516.647" rx="2.341" ry="4.873"/>
                    <ellipse fill="#D9D9DF" cx="327.921" cy="499.813" rx="1.962" ry="4.367"/>
                    <polygon fill="#E1E1E5" points="421.182,464.771 390.309,481.022 390.417,497.539 394.864,495.059 405.095,489.347 
                        423.418,479.119 423.418,465.566 423.418,463.592 423.239,463.689             "/>
                    <polygon fill="#EDBDBC" points="363.381,512.617 363.384,512.618 363.385,512.618 388.686,498.506 388.684,498.504 
                        388.688,498.503 388.674,495.596 388.606,481.915 388.61,481.914 388.61,481.912 388.611,481.912 390.309,481.019 
                        421.182,464.771 423.239,463.689 423.418,463.592 388.304,451.214 352.624,465.601 352.626,465.602 353.97,466.211 
                        367.97,472.557 386.889,481.133 386.889,481.157 386.964,497.627 353.706,480.641 352.626,480.09 324.784,491.379 
                        324.784,491.379             "/>
                    <path fill="#797978" d="M389.626,505.09c-3.222-1.399-6.869,1.79-8.145,7.122c-0.508,2.124-0.557,4.265-0.236,6.164
                        c0.484,2.867,1.82,5.182,3.759,6.024c3.222,1.396,6.869-1.792,8.145-7.125c0.513-2.144,0.559-4.304,0.227-6.216
                        C392.885,508.215,391.554,505.925,389.626,505.09z"/>
                    <path fill="#797978" d="M424.313,483.799c-3.222-1.397-6.868,1.791-8.145,7.124c-0.539,2.252-0.565,4.52-0.177,6.501
                        c0.53,2.711,1.837,4.879,3.7,5.685c3.222,1.4,6.868-1.788,8.145-7.122c0.483-2.017,0.557-4.053,0.288-5.877
                        C427.683,487.107,426.316,484.668,424.313,483.799z"/>
                </g>
                <polygon fill="#ABABAA" points="324.782,505.867 302.25,505.867 341.765,529.118 363.493,529.118      "/>
            </g>
            <g>
                <g>
                    <polygon fill="none" points="391.999,597.893 392.077,614.362 392.001,597.893 392,597.893            "/>
                    <polygon fill="none" points="399.976,611.794 410.211,606.084 410.207,606.082            "/>
                    <polygon fill="none" points="368.494,629.356 368.496,629.354 368.494,629.354            "/>
                    <polygon fill="none" points="373.082,589.292 359.082,582.946 373.069,589.296            "/>
                    <polygon fill="none" points="393.801,615.238 393.787,612.332 393.8,615.238          "/>
                    <polygon fill="#E19190" points="395.421,597.755 395.421,597.757 426.294,581.506             "/>
                    <polygon fill="#576D88" points="410.207,606.082 410.211,606.084 443.372,587.584 428.53,582.303 428.53,595.854           "/>
                    <polygon fill="#E19190" points="392,597.892 392,597.893 392.001,597.893 392.001,597.868 373.082,589.292 373.069,589.296             
                        "/>
                    <polygon fill="#E19190" points="393.722,598.649 393.724,598.648 393.722,598.648             "/>
                    <polygon fill="#E19190" points="368.572,645.838 368.572,645.835 368.57,645.836          "/>
                    <path fill="#576D88" d="M368.494,629.356v-0.002l-38.598-21.239h0.001l-0.002-0.001v14.489l38.675,23.233l-0.077-16.48H368.494z
                         M333.034,620.915c-1.085,0-1.962-1.954-1.962-4.366c0-2.412,0.878-4.367,1.962-4.367c1.082,0,1.96,1.955,1.96,4.367
                        C334.994,618.961,334.116,620.915,333.034,620.915z M363.41,638.256c-1.293,0-2.342-2.182-2.342-4.874
                        c0-2.69,1.048-4.871,2.342-4.871c1.293,0,2.341,2.181,2.341,4.871C365.751,636.074,364.703,638.256,363.41,638.256z"/>
                    <polygon fill="#D9D9DF" points="392.077,614.362 391.999,597.893 392,597.893 392,597.892 373.069,589.296 359.082,582.946 
                        357.738,582.337 357.738,596.826 358.818,597.376             "/>
                    <path fill="#798AA0" d="M443.374,587.584h-0.002l-33.161,18.5l-10.235,5.71l-4.447,2.482l-0.108-16.519v-0.002l-1.697,0.893
                        l-0.001,0.001l-0.003,0.001l0.067,13.682l0.014,2.906h0l-0.004,0.002l0.002,0.001l-25.301,14.113h-0.001l-0.002,0.001h-0.001
                        l0.077,16.48l0.003-0.001l17.785-10.723c-0.321-1.9-0.272-4.041,0.237-6.165c1.276-5.332,4.922-8.522,8.145-7.122
                        c1.927,0.835,3.258,3.126,3.75,5.97l22.614-13.636c-0.387-1.98-0.361-4.249,0.177-6.501c1.276-5.333,4.923-8.521,8.145-7.124
                        c2.003,0.87,3.369,3.309,3.811,6.311l10.138-6.113V587.584z"/>
                    <ellipse fill="#D9D9DF" cx="363.41" cy="633.383" rx="2.342" ry="4.873"/>
                    <ellipse fill="#D9D9DF" cx="333.034" cy="616.548" rx="1.962" ry="4.367"/>
                    <polygon fill="#E1E1E5" points="426.294,581.506 395.421,597.757 395.529,614.275 399.976,611.794 410.207,606.082 
                        428.53,595.854 428.53,582.303 428.53,580.328 428.352,580.424            "/>
                    <polygon fill="#9AA7B8" points="368.494,629.354 368.496,629.354 368.498,629.354 393.799,615.241 393.796,615.24 393.8,615.238 
                        393.787,612.332 393.719,598.65 393.722,598.649 393.722,598.648 393.724,598.648 395.421,597.755 426.294,581.506 
                        428.352,580.424 428.53,580.328 393.417,567.949 357.736,582.336 357.738,582.337 359.082,582.946 373.082,589.292 
                        392.001,597.868 392.001,597.893 392.077,614.362 358.818,597.376 357.738,596.826 329.897,608.114 329.896,608.114             "/>
                    <path fill="#797978" d="M394.739,621.825c-3.222-1.399-6.869,1.79-8.145,7.122c-0.509,2.124-0.558,4.265-0.237,6.165
                        c0.484,2.867,1.82,5.181,3.76,6.023c3.222,1.397,6.869-1.791,8.145-7.125c0.513-2.143,0.559-4.304,0.228-6.216
                        C397.997,624.951,396.666,622.66,394.739,621.825z"/>
                    <path fill="#797978" d="M429.426,600.534c-3.223-1.396-6.869,1.791-8.145,7.124c-0.538,2.252-0.564,4.521-0.177,6.501
                        c0.53,2.711,1.838,4.879,3.7,5.686c3.222,1.4,6.868-1.789,8.145-7.122c0.483-2.018,0.557-4.053,0.288-5.878
                        C432.795,603.843,431.429,601.404,429.426,600.534z"/>
                </g>
                <polygon fill="#ABABAA" points="329.895,622.602 307.362,622.602 346.877,645.854 368.605,645.854         "/>
            </g>
            <g>
                <polygon fill="#ABABAA" points="515.037,493.158 494.906,493.158 565.782,538.273 589.906,538.273         "/>
                <g>
                    <polygon fill="none" points="566.432,490.317 566.354,506.787 566.43,490.317 566.432,490.317             "/>
                    <polygon fill="none" points="558.455,504.219 548.221,498.508 548.223,498.507            "/>
                    <polygon fill="none" points="589.936,521.78 589.935,521.779 589.936,521.777             "/>
                    <polygon fill="none" points="585.349,481.717 599.35,475.371 585.361,481.721             "/>
                    <polygon fill="none" points="564.63,507.663 564.644,504.756 564.632,507.663             "/>
                    <polygon fill="#E19190" points="563.01,490.179 563.01,490.182 532.137,473.931           "/>
                    <polygon fill="#D4A139" points="548.223,498.507 548.221,498.508 515.06,480.009 529.9,474.727 529.9,488.279          "/>
                    <polygon fill="#E19190" points="566.432,490.316 566.432,490.317 566.43,490.317 566.43,490.293 585.349,481.717 
                        585.361,481.721             "/>
                    <polygon fill="#E19190" points="564.709,491.074 564.708,491.072 564.709,491.072             "/>
                    <polygon fill="#E19190" points="589.859,538.262 589.859,538.26 589.861,538.261          "/>
                    <path fill="#DDB461" d="M589.94,521.78l-0.078,16.48l38.675-23.233v-14.49l-0.001,0.002l0,0l-38.599,21.238v0.003H589.94z
                         M623.438,508.974c0-2.412,0.877-4.367,1.96-4.367c1.084,0,1.962,1.955,1.962,4.367s-0.878,4.366-1.962,4.366
                        C624.315,513.34,623.438,511.386,623.438,508.974z M592.68,525.807c0-2.691,1.049-4.871,2.342-4.871s2.342,2.18,2.342,4.871
                        c0,2.692-1.049,4.874-2.342,4.874S592.68,528.499,592.68,525.807z"/>
                    <polygon fill="#D9D9DF" points="566.354,506.787 566.432,490.317 566.432,490.317 566.432,490.316 585.361,481.721 
                        599.35,475.371 600.693,474.762 600.693,489.25 599.612,489.801           "/>
                    <path fill="#D4A139" d="M515.057,480.009h0.003l33.161,18.499l10.234,5.711l4.446,2.48l0.108-16.518v-0.003l1.698,0.894
                        l0.001,0.002l0.002,0.001l-0.067,13.681l-0.014,2.907h0.002l0.002,0.001l-0.002,0.002l25.303,14.113l0,0l0.002,0.001h0.003
                        l-0.078,16.48l-0.002-0.001l-17.786-10.724c0.321-1.899,0.271-4.04-0.236-6.164c-1.276-5.332-4.923-8.521-8.145-7.122
                        c-1.927,0.835-3.259,3.125-3.75,5.97l-22.616-13.636c0.389-1.982,0.362-4.249-0.176-6.501c-1.276-5.333-4.923-8.521-8.145-7.124
                        c-2.004,0.87-3.369,3.309-3.812,6.31l-10.138-6.113V480.009z"/>
                    <ellipse fill="#D9D9DF" cx="595.021" cy="525.808" rx="2.342" ry="4.873"/>
                    <ellipse fill="#D9D9DF" cx="625.397" cy="508.973" rx="1.962" ry="4.367"/>
                    <polygon fill="#E1E1E5" points="532.137,473.931 563.01,490.182 562.901,506.699 558.455,504.219 548.223,498.507 529.9,488.279 
                        529.9,474.727 529.9,472.752 530.08,472.849          "/>
                    <polygon fill="#E5C788" points="589.936,521.777 589.935,521.779 589.935,521.779 564.632,507.666 564.634,507.664 
                        564.632,507.663 564.644,504.756 564.711,491.075 564.709,491.074 564.709,491.072 564.708,491.072 563.01,490.179 
                        532.137,473.931 530.08,472.849 529.9,472.752 565.015,460.374 600.694,474.761 600.693,474.762 599.35,475.371 585.349,481.717 
                        566.43,490.293 566.43,490.317 566.354,506.787 599.612,489.801 600.693,489.25 628.535,500.539 628.535,500.539            "/>
                    <path fill="#797978" d="M563.692,514.25c3.222-1.399,6.868,1.79,8.145,7.122c0.508,2.124,0.558,4.265,0.236,6.164
                        c-0.484,2.867-1.82,5.182-3.76,6.024c-3.222,1.396-6.867-1.791-8.145-7.125c-0.513-2.144-0.558-4.304-0.227-6.216
                        C560.434,517.375,561.766,515.085,563.692,514.25z"/>
                    <path fill="#797978" d="M529.006,492.959c3.222-1.397,6.868,1.791,8.145,7.124c0.538,2.252,0.564,4.52,0.176,6.501
                        c-0.529,2.711-1.837,4.879-3.699,5.685c-3.222,1.4-6.867-1.789-8.145-7.122c-0.482-2.018-0.557-4.054-0.288-5.878
                        C525.637,496.268,527.002,493.829,529.006,492.959z"/>
                </g>
            </g>

    </svg>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a really simple solution!

On the 's I want to open links, I just added

```
onclick="window.open('www.google.com')"
```